# Airflow: How to pass xcom from parent dag to subdag

Tags: python, airflow

Considering a parent dag that pushes value to xcom, how to retrieve dag from subdag?

What I've tried:

```
#parent_dag.py

PARENT_DAG_NAME = "MyParentDag"
CHILD_DAG_NAME = "MyChildDag"

main_dag = DAG(
  dag_id=PARENT_DAG_NAME,
  schedule_interval="@hourly",
  start_date=DAG_START_DATE
)


def push_value(**kwargs):
    ''' push into Xcom '''
    return [1, 2]

t1 = PythonOperator(task_id='push_value',
                       python_callable=push_value,
                       retries=3,
                       dag=main_dag)

subdag_1 = SubDagOperator(
  subdag=Sub_Dag1(
      PARENT_DAG_NAME,
      CHILD_DAG_NAME,
      main_dag.start_date,
      main_dag.schedule_interval,
      "'{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_value', dag_id='" + PARENT_DAG_NAME + "' }}'"
  ),
  task_id=CHILD_DAG_NAME,
  dag=main_dag,
)
t1 >> subdag_1
```

And the child subdag:

```
#subdag1.py


def use_pushed_val(pushed_val, ds, **kwargs):
    log.info(pushed_val)
    return pushed_val

def Sub_Dag1(parent_dag_name, child_dag_name, start_date, schedule_interval, pushed_val):
  dag = DAG(
    '%s.%s' % (parent_dag_name, child_dag_name),
    schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
    start_date=start_date,
  )

  childTask = PythonOperator(
      task_id='child_task',
      python_callable=use_pushed_val,
      op_kwargs = {'pushed_val' : pushed_val},
      provide_context=True,
      dag=dag
    )

return dag
```

Instead of child subdag to log and return the `[1,2]`, it returned string `'{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_value', dag_id='MyParentDag' }}'`

Comment: Were you able to find the way to pass value from DAG to sub-DAG?

Comment: It is a working solution just add a missing parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='push_value', dag_id='" + PARENT_DAG_NAME + "')}}
```

In the above code a parenthesis is missing

Comment: Yes it solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I saw that you've already set the provide_context=True, so that's good. This is how i pass variable between parent/child dags using the **context argument.

```
def push_value(**context):
    context['ti'].xcom_push(key='my_key', value='my_value')

def use_pushed_val(**context):
    value_from_parent = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids=t1.task_id, key='my_key')
```

Comment: It have to be added dag_id='master_id" to xcom_pull